# How to use linq2Xml without the possibility of a null exception?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I wrote this simple linq-to-xml query and it seems that null exception could not be avoided using the the linq syntax. Am I using it wrong? What should be the right (and short) Linq2Xml syntax?

#### The linq2Xml query

```
var userData =
    queryUserResponseData.Elements("user")
        .Single(u => u.Element("username").Value == userName);
```

#### The XML

```
<data>
    <user>
        <username>User1</username>
        <userid>123</userid>
    </user>
    <user>
        <username>User2</username>
        <userid>456</userid>
    </user>
    <user>
        <userid>999</userid>
    </user>
</data>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XElement and XAttribute have some explicit conversion operators to convert their value to the specific types. They are so useful because, return null when the Element or Attribute is missing.

```
var userData = queryUserResponseData.Elements("user").Single(u => (string)u.Element("username") == userName);
```

Comment: +1 for `(string)u.Element("username")`. Answer would be perfect if there was some additional explanation why/how this solves the problem.

Comment: @dtb thanks for your upvote and so sorry for the lack of explanation.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment to Ahmad Mageed's answer:

> The problem is actually at `u.Element("username").Value` where the Resharper notifies me about a possible null exception

it sounds like you might be worrying about a potential rather than real problem. You know that your data will mean that you will always return 1 result, however ReSharper doesn't have access to your data so it's highlighting the fact that if there were no results it would generate a null reference exception.

You can do one of three things:

1. Ignore the warning and do nothing.
2. Recode to account for this so that there's no chance of an exception (see the other answers).
3. Wrap the Linq in a `try {} catch {}` so that if the "unthinkable" happens your program won't crash.

Only you can really decide which you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Single` means you expect there to be exactly 1 result. When more results are returned, Single will throw an exception. You could use `First` to get the first item, or `Last` for the last one. For multiple items you'll want to loop over the results and access each one individually.

If no matching result exists, you can use `SingleOrDefault` to return a `null` value or the default value of the type used.

Is `queryUserResponseData` an XElement or an XDocument? If it's an XDocument you need to access the XML's root first, such as:

```
var userData = queryUserResponseData.Root.Elements("user")
                 .Single(u => u.Element("username").Value == userName);
```

Apart from that, searching for User1 or User2 in your sample would work. However, if you searched for **User3**, which doesn't exist, Single will throw an exception. In that case you should use SingleOrDefault:

```
var userData = queryUserResponseData.Elements("user")
                 .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Element("username").Value == "User3");
```

Comment: I do expect for 1 result. The problem is actually at `u.Element("username").Value` where the Resharper notifies me about a possible null exception.

Comment: ReSharper is likely being cautious and indicating that the "username" element may not exist, in which case the exception would occur. See @ChrisF's response below. @Matajon's answer is a clean way to avoid it too.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment to Ahmad's answer, I presume you get NullReferenceException when element doesn't have  node. You can fix it like this -

```
var userData =
    doc.Elements("user")
    .Single(u => u.Element("username") != null && u.Element("username").Value == userName);
```

But if username node is required there by DTD or XSD or you are sure all elements will have username node, you can simply ignore ReSharper warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
var userData = queryUserResponseData.Elements("user")
    .Select(u => u.Element("username"))
    .Where(uNode => uNode != null)
    .Single(uName => uName.Value == userName);
```